# API service on port 8080 is not responding to KONG Container on same machine

Tags: networking, gateway

I am using Kong Gateway to proxy requests to API services.

The Kong gatway is running in a container on the same machine but seems that it cannot access to the API service (*504 ERROR bad gateway*). Is it because that port 8080 may not be accesble because of firewall rules (Linux)? How I can check it out and how is this possible that the container cannot access a port on same machine?

I started a service on localhost:8000, using Kong Gateway on the container. Trying to access the services by Kong Gateway but getting "*Connection refused error*".

Comment: what `firewall rules` have you created? Have you tried disabling the firewall as a test?

Comment: I did not make any rule yet because not accessing from the container is strange and I am not really familiar with this LINUX issue. ufw status is inactive and meaning the firewall is disabled.